# I want to know how to perform mlxtend stacking CV regressor in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to perform a stacking CV regressor using random forest, lasso and support vector regressor models as independent models and random forest as meta regressor. I want to know how to perform the same in pyspark.The below mentioned code is in python and I want to convert in pyspark.

I couldn't find stacking cv regressor in pyspark MLlib library

```
svr = SVR(kernel='linear')
lasso = Lasso()
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=5, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

# Starting from v0.16.0, StackingCVRegressor supports
# `random_state` to get deterministic result.
stack = StackingCVRegressor(regressors=(svr, lasso, rf), meta_regressor=rf,random_state=RANDOM_SEED)
```